# IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1(64) : Unsupported java version Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_79-b15: Java 1.8 or later is required

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea-2016

Currently I set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to 1.7

When I try to open the file **`idea64.exe`** (path : `..\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\bin\idea64.exe`) below error is populated

[image]

> *Unsupported java version
>
>   Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_79-b15: Java 1.8 or later is required.*

From the above error I understood that I have to set my `JAVA_HOME` to 1.8, but I don't want to set `JAVA_HOME` to 1.8.

I believe there should be a configuration file where in I can point to Java-8 and fix this, can anyone please let me know where can I do the configuration changes?

Comment: On Linux there is a startup script. You could add a BAT file to set the environment variable and call the exe

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should create `IDEA_JDK_64` environment variable and set its value to `JDK8` instance location on your computer.

This `JDK8` instance can be used only for `idea` and `JAVA_HOME` can point to the Java 7 at the same time without any problems.

Via [documentation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under):

> idea64.exe uses this JDK search sequence:
>
> - IDEA_JDK_64 environment variable
> - ..\jre64 directory
> - system Registry
> - JDK_HOME environment variable
> - JAVA_HOME environment variable

Comment: I know this question was about a Windows installation, but it's not tagged windows and IDEA usually works pretty much the same on Windows and Linux. So I'll mention that on Ubuntu 16.04/Xenial setting IDEA_JDK_64 to the Java 8 JDK didn't work. IDEA failed to start, reporting `Cannot start under Java <JAVA_HOME-version>: Java 1.8 or later is required.` where <JAVA_HOME-version> is $JAVA_HOME .

Comment: However, on Ubuntu 16.04/Xenial setting IDEA_JDK to the Java 8 JDK dir (eg. /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/ ) does work.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the IDEA_JDK_64 environment variable pointing to the current JDK 8 installation didn't work for me on Windows 7.

What worked was starting IDEA from its script residing in:

`<your location of>\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.1\bin\idea.bat`

On Windows, one can map a shortcut to that location and change its icon to:

`<your location of>\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.1\bin\idea.ico`

Comment: this worked for me when environment variable solution didn't

Answer (score 1):

i found answers above a bit unclear being new to this.

your first step would be to open environment variables, search in windows.

in **user variables** create a new entry for `IDEA_JDK_64`

add the path to the JDK version you wish to use, for me it was  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1`

this should do the job.

Comment: Hafiz, your solution worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

first : jdk -version ?? 1.7 or 1.8 ,so change this environment variable;
then : uninstall  idea 
;end : install idea

this is a stupid method ,but it works!

Comment: because   64 --> jdk8  , so use 32 .

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you open IDEA with **idea64.exe**, try **idea.exe**.